# Alternative to Mac OS X Finder

Tags: macos, mac, finder

Is there any Free alternative to that?

Comment: I think this has been asked before, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @alex, i first search it here and when i did not find that i asked it, if i have not found it pelase direct me to that, thanks.

Comment: As I said, I'm not sure if it's a duplicate. Maybe it only sounds familiar.

Comment: related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4944/are-there-any-free-alternatives-to-finder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not free, but very good Finder alternative: [Path Finder](http://cocoatech.com/).

Comment: Thanks man, though its not free but its awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [MuCommander](http://www.mucommander.com/). It's free, cross-platform and easy to use.

Comment: thanks but is there anything which work like Finder but give options which Finder dont give you... e.g; cut paste etc..

Comment: You can build services in Automator, that can be contextual to Finder, Files and Folders.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t offer quite the same experience that a real cut-and-paste solution would (which would not be too comfortable with standard Finder either, because you can’t easily select the root folder in Finder once you’ve clicked an item in the folder), because I think it hasn’t got a shortcut and there is no easy way in OS X to get to the context menu using the keyboard only. And without a key it’s only half the fun.

However, you should have a look at [FinderPop](http://www.finderpop.com/). (It’s not yet all feature complete on Snow Leopard as with earlier versions, but you can already use it.)
You can see it more like a plugin to the context menu of Finder and some other programs.

Basically it adds a selection of folders to the Finder context menu and whenever you context a file, it allows you to select a target among these folders and then select the action (move or copy).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that [BumpTop](http://bumptop.com/) is going to be gratis (much less libre), but it is in beta on the mac right now. Also available for windows.

Comment: To save you the trip, Bump Top was acquired by Google in Apr 2010, no updates are available on their site since then, and downloads are not available.

Answer (score 0):

[Forklift](http://www.binarynights.com/). Because Path Finder isn't that good of an alternative.